# How do you capture escaped quotes from a file when using "while read line" loops?

Tags: bash, zsh, jq

I'm trying to access data from a file full of JSON objects, where the string fields may or may not have escaped quotes in them.

When I try to process it using `while read line ; do echo ; done < input.txt`, it pukes because of the unbalanced number of quotes.

I have this input file:

```
$ cat input.txt 
{"sku":"1234", "desc":"Necklace 18\" long", "img":"https://provider.com/12345.jpg", "imgView":"A"}
{"sku":"1234", "desc":"Necklace 18\" long", "img":"https://provider.com/12346.jpg", "imgView":"B"}
```

When I use `read` to capture it on the way in, I lose the backslash.

```
$ while read line ; do echo "${line}" ; done < input.txt
{"sku":"1234", "desc":"Necklace 18" long", "img":"https://provider.com/12345.jpg", "imgView":"A"}
{"sku":"1234", "desc":"Necklace 18" long", "img":"https://provider.com/12346.jpg", "imgView":"B"}

$ while read line ; do echo "${line}" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' ; done < input.txt
{"sku":"1234", "desc":"Necklace 18" long", "img":"https://provider.com/12345.jpg", "imgView":"A"}
{"sku":"1234", "desc":"Necklace 18" long", "img":"https://provider.com/12346.jpg", "imgView":"B"}
```

I have this workaround that I'll use for now to unblock myself. But it's ugly and verbose.

```
#Showing that it's preserving the escape
$ input=input.txt ; counter=1; length=$(cat ${input} | wc -l)
$ while [ ${counter} -le ${length} ] ; do data=$(tail -n +${counter} ${input} | head -n 1 ) ; echo ${data} ; counter=$(( counter + 1)) ; done 
{"sku":"1234", "desc":"Necklace 18\" long", "img":"https://provider.com/12345.jpg", "imgView":"A"}
{"sku":"1234", "desc":"Necklace 18\" long", "img":"https://provider.com/12346.jpg", "imgView":"B"}

#Showing that jq can actually process the data now
$ input=input.txt ; counter=1; length=$(cat ${input} | wc -l)
$ while [ ${counter} -le ${length} ] ; do desc=$(tail -n +${counter} ${input} | head -n 1 | jq '.desc' -r) ; echo ${desc} ; counter=$(( counter + 1)) ; done 
Necklace 18" long
Necklace 18" long
```

I feel like I have to get way too low level into how the shell is handling the input. There has to be an easier way, or a flag or something that I'm missing.

Comment: Use `read -r` to treat backslashes literally instead of as an escape character.

Comment: Some versions of `echo` also do weird things with backslashes; use `printf '%s\n' "$line"` instead.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. That should definitely be RTFM material, but `man read` was just the manual page telling me about shell built-ins.

Comment: @Barmar - I confirmed it works for me. If you give it as an answer, I'll mark as answered. Thank you again.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Only `echo -e` does that.

Comment: @Barmar *Some* versions of `echo` (in some modes) only translate backslashes if given the `-e` option; others (or the same one in other modes) do... different things. Stéphane Chazelas has a good explanation of why it's such a mess in [this Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819). Also, note that the [POSIX spec for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) says that on XSI-conformant systems, backslashes *will* be processed (and doesn't mention `-e`).

Comment: Your question can't be about [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh] at the same time; which is it?

Comment: @GordonDavisson The old guidance about `echo` obviously is moot if you are using a specific shell whose built-in `echo` does not do that. (But I do agree that `printf` is better simply because it avoids this distraction.)

Comment: @tripleee You can't even count on a shell's builtin `echo` for consistent behavior. I once had a bunch of my scripts break because an OS update included a version of bash compiled with different options, which changed its behavior. That's when I really got the `printf` religion.

Answer (score 0):

The escaping of the quotes inside your example data is valid JSON throughout. Depending on what you intend to do inside your loop, maybe it can be accomplished by `jq` itself, which automatically iterates over each object for you. You can even use it to unescape a given string using the `--raw-output` option like so:

```sh
 jq --raw-output '.desc' input.txt
```

```
Necklace 18" long
Necklace 18" long
```

Again, all depends on what is your actual goal is inside the loop. The following example even encodes for HTML using the `@html` builtin:

```sh
jq --raw-output '@html "<h1>\(.desc)</h1>\n<img src=\"\(.img)\"/>\n"' input.txt
```

```html
<h1>Necklace 18&quot; long</h1>
<img src="https://provider.com/12345.jpg"/>

<h1>Necklace 18&quot; long</h1>
<img src="https://provider.com/12346.jpg"/>
```